# jquery: function to end another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$('#start')` executes the function `myFunction()` and `$('#stop')` end it. How do I stop `myFunction()` from executing?

```
function myFunction() {
     $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
          $('#field').html(e.pageY)
     });
}


$('#start').click(function() {
    myFunction();
});


$('#stop').click(function() {
   //stop myFunction
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out, you actually want to unbind the event handler. You can use [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) for this:

```
$('#stop').click(function() {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

But this will also remove all other `mousemove` event handlers, that might be attached by other plugins or similar (I mean, you attach to the `document` element not a "custom" element, so it can be that other JavaScript code also binds handlers to this element).

To prevent this, you can use [event namespaces](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events). You would attach the listener with:

```
function myFunction() {
     $(document).bind('mousemove.namespace', function(e) {
          $('#field').html(e.pageY);
     });
}
```

and unbind:

```
$('#stop').click(function() {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove.namespace');
});
```

This would only remove your specific handler.

Comment: this is more practical. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're not stopping the function from executing. Your `myFunction()` simply attaches a callback to an event listener, which is called whenever the mouse is moved on the document. The callback function is invoked and is terminated immediately.

You'd simply want to unbind the callback from the event listener. Check out the other answers for concrete examples.

Comment: its not stopping it from executing.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to use bind and unbind, like so:

```
function myFunction() {
     $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
          $('#field').html(e.pageY)
     });
}

$('#start').bind('click', myFunction);

$('#stop').click(function() {
   $('#start').unbind('click', myFunction);
});
```

Comment: It should be `bind('click', myFunction)`, not `bind('click', myFunction())`. Similar for `unbind`.

Comment: Thanks KennyTM, I have never actually used jQuery's binding capabilities with named functions.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the jQuery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) methods. For example:

```
function myFunction() {
     $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
          $('#field').html(e.pageY)
     });
}


$('#start').bind('click.myFunction', function() {
    myFunction();
});

$('#stop').bind('click', function() {
    $('#start').unbind('click.myFunction');
});
```

Comment: No worries. The second half of Felix's answer is even better.